# Is my fantasy map unrealistic and/or too small?

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, map-making

I've finally drawn out a map of the world in which my fantasy novel (mostly) is set in hopes of creating more countries and deepening political tension between the existing ones through figuring out borders, trade routes etc. But having done that, I feel that it is too small and/or unrealistic. Now I know that the map not finished yet and is merely a layout, but I want to make changes as early as possible.

Any help or opinion would be greatly appreciated! :)

P.S. Details:  I feel that the map is too small because of how it looks compared to other fantasy worlds and even our own. Politics look good on a larger scope and I'm worried that this map doesn't convey that - it looks like a fragment, but is meant to be all there is in the populated world. The planet having such a small landmass feels slightly unrealistic, as well, especially if competed to the huge (maybe seemingly so) continents in some other works of the genre.

[image]

Comment: welcome to worldbuilding. If you don't give use the scale of the map it is impossible for us to judge the size, and you are not giving us any other helping detail

Comment: Also @A.I. welcome to Worldbuilding!!

Comment: @Dubukay Thanks!

Comment: @Dubukay, I think it still misses what the OP thinks might be unrealistic.

Comment: @Punintended Thanks a lot! I actually thought Westeros is a lot bigger. Looking at the maps of different fantasy worlds, it appears that most of them have huge continents, which can be intimidating, so it's a relief to hear that mine is about average.

Comment: @L.Dutch OP is worried about the proper scale for his continent - he’s worried that it’s not the proper size for a continental landmass, if I understand it correctly. You accurately pointed out that we need a size scale, which has been provided. I’m not sure what “other details” you are expecting, but this feels fairly open-and-shut to me.

Comment: @Dubukay Yes, I was worried that it is both too small to be a continent geographically and that it is way too small for an average fantasy landmass. Answers in the comments rule, though, so it's fine. Appreciate your support!

Comment: @L.Dutch, we get vague, "does my map look OK?" questions on this site all the time.  They're likely the most subjective and most discussion-prone questions we get.  This one deserved to be closed until the scale was included.  Now it should be reopened.  The only thing I think is missing is the [tag:reality-check] tag.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour]. Please remember that [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).  Thus the use of the [tag:reality-check] tag.  It forces answerers to justify their observations.  Thanks.

Comment: @JBH, the other questions we get about plausibility of maps also explain what is the problem the OP is struggling with (i.e. rivers, climate, etc.). Here the OP only states "I feel that it is too small and/or unrealistic", nothing else. How can you judge the plausibility based just on this information?

Comment: Australia is the Earth's smallest continent. It's about 4,000km east to west, and about 3,500km north to south (if you include Tasmania). Landmasses smaller than this are not considered to be continents by geographers, but geologists tend to disagree.

Comment: @L.Dutch, ah, so what you're saying is "too small for what?" and the "what" is missing.  Personally, I think he addressed that with his comments about countries, tensions, trade routes, etc., but that could be made more clear.  A.I.?  Why do you think the map is too small, in two sentences or less.  Thanks!

Comment: @JBH I feel that the map is too small because of how it looks compared to other fantasy worlds and even our own (some parts wouldn't even be considered continents, as is stated above). Politics look good on a larger scope and I'm worried that this map doesn't convey that - it looks like a fragment, but is meant to be all there is in the populated world.

Comment: @A.I., please put the details in the question. Comments can be deleted at any moments (and these will soon end in the chat), while questions are far more stable.

Comment: And yes, I agree that I was too vague in the OP, I'll be sure too be more scecific in my future posts/questions. It's very nice that you try to help me despite this.

Comment: @L.Dutch Of course, I was about to do it. Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: The issue with this map is that it is not obvious how it folds to wrap around the world. For this reason alone it currently looks like a fragment of a larger map.

Comment: @NofP Wow, thanks a lot! I've never actually thought about this and now I feel it really might be the cause of the issue.

Comment: Small maps are fine, many fantasy settings use small maps, look at middle earth or westeros. They do not use a map of the entire world just the small part of it your story takes place in. Pre-industrial technology meant travel was slow and people rarely travels that far, traveling the entire globe is something that would make someone famous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry I couldn't upload the gif -- too big! So I made a series of stills, 45deg apart & rotating Earthwise.

First of all, I don't think your land masses (the plain / white areas) look bad. I mean, if you look at maps of early Earth, you see all kinds of wacky land masses. So, image 1 looks pretty good, actually!

**First issue:** Way too much land!  As you rotate around, the first thing you'll notice is that you've got about 60 to 70% land.  You have one medium sized continent and one small continent in a land-locked ocean-sea. This may or may not be intentional! But it is something I want to draw to your attention, as I think this will screw with global climate and weather patterns.

**Second Issue:**  You didn't give me a complete map! If you look on maps 2 and 3, you'll notice a large, dark rift.  No, that's not a geological feature your world's Chris Columbus will nosedive into!  That's the dark smudge at the left edge of your paper.  To the west of that dark chasm is the right edge of your map, which has no coastline! You'll either have to draw a coastline somewhere along the right side of your map, or else add paper and draw a bigger map!

**Third Issue:** You gave me the wonkiest scale you could possibly do!  Your "2000 mi line" is at approximately 55deg north.  Earth is about 40075km in circumference at the equator. I plugged some numbers into calculators for determining circle diameter at a given latitude:

[This one](https://rechneronline.de/earth-radius/) tells me that at 55deg the Earth's diameter is 12727.654km
[This one](http://www.easysurf.cc/circle.htm#ctod) tells me that at 55deg the Earth's circumference is 39,985.1km

At the same latitude, your world is approximately 4100 miles or so (there's about 20deg of longitude error (4000 mi plus whatever distance is equal to 20 deg.))

The circumference of your world at that same latitude is only 6598.31km, so your whole planet is indeed quite small!

**Conclusions:** Your world is (probably) *nòt* unrealistic, but its land to water ratio is something you'll have to explore on your own.  I've seen "wet Mars" maps that look pretty much like your world: a lot of land, very little sea.

According to your scale, it is small.  Whether it is too small, or too big or just right, of course, is going to be up to you!

**Suggestions:** First thing! Next time you draw a world map, please just put your scale at the equator!! I'm not a maths whiz and using those calculators pretty much caused my brain to crash.  Second, if you want a bigger world, you have two options: first, draw more world!; second, multiply that "2000 mile" line by a factor of 2.  I *thìnk* that will give you an Earth sized planet on the cheap. Third, fix the western coastline of the World Sea.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for such an awesome, detailed answer!! A lot of food for thought :) Hope you have an amazing day!